# command not available in debian live cd

Tags: debian

Being interested about debian, I tried using QEMU to run debian under windows, but I realize that some of my commonly used command cannot be used. I can use `ls`; `mkdir`, but not `password root`; `pstree`, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `password` is not a standard linux command. Try `passwd` instead.
2. `pstree` is likely not installed by default. Install the `psmisc` package.

Comment: so, should I run an apt-get update first?

Comment: Yes, that's usually a good idea to do before installing packages.